# Newest version of a library not available in xenial, how can I install it?

Tags: updates, ppa, repository

I'm trying to install `glfw 3.2.1-1` which is available here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+source/glfw3

But my Ubuntu installation uses "xenial" repositories, which has an older version of this library. How can I install the package from the "yakkety" repo?

Answer (score 0):

You could either do that with some combination of [pinning](https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/how-to-install-packages-from-a-newer-distribution-without-installing-unwanted-6584fa93208f) and older releases [servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release), or you could just use the right ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cginternals/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglfw3
```